# Batch file to delete files after a certain amount of time in folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way I can create a batch file to delete files from a folder if they are in there for a certain number of days.

For example:

A files is in folder "edited" and has been there for a month, and if a file is in there for a month of longer, the batch file deletes it.

I'm guessing I would create a batch file then have it run on a schedule to check for files that have been there too long, I just don't know how to write the batch file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start learning `forfiles`: http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googled a little, seems this is the solution:

```
forfiles -p "c:\your\folder" -s -m *.* /D -<number of days> /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Change “C:\your\folder” to the directory to which you are saving the files you want to delete on a schedule. Note that the -40 refers to the day after which all files should be deleted so change the -40 if required.

Have a look at this post [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

Comment: Do I have to schedule the batch file to run, or will it run automatically if a file is in there longer than x amount of time?

Comment: You'd have to schedule it. The other way would be to make a loop with a timeout involved. :)