# Windows batch file delete files older than X days but leave a min of X files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have see the older posts where you can delete files older than X days, such as this one [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days). I'd like to add an additional filter to this so that if the backup I am running is not happening for 2 weeks, then it wouldn't delete all my backups.

I know with this:

```
forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.* -d <number of days> -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

That you can delete older than X days but how do I add the condition above and have it leave a minimum of Z files behind before it does the delete?

Example:

Lets say I want to delete files older than 14 days but keep a minimum of 5 files with the files below:

```
Jan 1 - backup1.zip
Jan 2 - backup2.zip
Jan 3 - backup3.zip
Jan 4 - backup4.zip
Jan 5 - backup5.zip
Jan 6 - backup6.zip
Jan 7-20 no backups done
Jan 21st - script runs and removed old files
```

With the example code that deletes all files older than 14 days, all of my backup files would be deleted and I'd be left with no backups. I'd like the script to see that only 6 files remains and keep a minimum of 5 files.

Make sense? Is this possible through windows batch files?

**FOR CLARITY**

This is part of my batch file that I have:

```
cd /d %BKUPDIR%
FOR /f "skip=14 delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c %1*.zip ^2^>nul') DO IF EXIST "%%~fA" ECHO "%%~fA" >>%LOGFILE%
FOR /f "skip=14 delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c %1*.zip ^2^>nul') DO IF EXIST "%%~fA" DEL "%%~fA" >>%LOGFILE%
FOR /f "skip=14 delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c %1*.log ^2^>nul') DO IF EXIST "%%~fA" ECHO "%%~fA" >>%LOGFILE%
FOR /f "skip=14 delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c %1*.log ^2^>nul') DO IF EXIST "%%~fA" DEL "%%~fA" >>%LOGFILE%
```

The files are zip and log files that I am deleting and they all reside in the same folder.

Comment: you want to keep newest or oldest files?

Comment: @npocmaka Great question, I'd want to keep the newest file.

Comment: are all your files located in the same folder or they might be in sub-folders? If they are located in the same folder are there any other files/folders there?

Comment: @CristiFati I have added additional information that I hope answers your question.

Comment: I look at the batch file and I think it should work. (After it's done you could echo the file name and delete it in the same `for`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This script will delete all zip and log files older than 14 days, keeping a minimum of the 5 most recent of each (10 total), regardless of age.

Note that the FORFILES /D option is based on last modified date, so I did not use creation date for ordering my DIR command.

The FORFILES command is quite slow, so once I detect the a file older than 14 days old, I don't bother running FORFILES again, since I know all remaining files are that age or older.

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\yourBackupPath"
for %%X in (zip log) do (
  set "skip=1"
  for /f "skip=5 delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d /tw *.%%X') do (
    if defined skip forfiles /d -14 /m "%%F" >nul 2>nul && set "skip="
    if not defined skip del "%%F" 
  )
)
```

Comment: tyvm I'll give it a try!

Comment: Seems to work but I'm getting a file not found after each run of it. I have tested it several ways, should I be worried?

Comment: I can't imagine where the "FILE NOT FOUND" message is coming from, unless you are missing one of the file types (.zip or .log). If that is the source of the error message, then you should be fine (assuming it is OK for the file type to be missing of course).

Comment: Ah that was it, there were no log files in the directory. thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like gibberish from Mars but works. Thanks :-)

Comment: nice answer @dbenham, but what to pass in outer for loop if I don't want to pass any particular file type(want to delete a file of any type)

Comment: can this solution be used for folders as well?