# Java file that deletes both folders and files works on server 2000 but not 2008

Tags: java, windows-server-2008, command-line-arguments

I wrote this code for a 2001 server, running java 1.3. It deletes folders and files but not the main folder. Which is intended.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.security.InvalidParameterException;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainCopy {
String path;
int numDays;
File rootFolder;

public MainCopy(String path, int numDays) {
    this.path = path;
    this.numDays = numDays;
    this.rootFolder = new File(path); 

}

public void deleteFile(File delFile) {

    if (delFile.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = delFile.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            deleteFile(files[i]);
        }

        if(delFile.list().length==0){   
            if (!delFile.equals(rootFolder)) {

                delFile.delete();
                System.out.println("Deleted: " 
                        + delFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }



    }else{
        long diff = new Date().getTime() - delFile.lastModified();
        if (diff >= numDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {

            delFile.delete();
            System.out.println("Deleted: " 
                    + delFile.getAbsolutePath());

        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String path;
    String numDays;

    if (args.length == 0) {
        throw new InvalidParameterException("Arguments can not be empty. \n"
                + "Expected arguments are <PATH> <Deletion cut off>");

    } else if (args.length == 2) {

        path = args[0];
        numDays = args[1];

        File dir = new File(path);
        int num;

        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(numDays);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Delete cut off must be a number");
        }

        if ((dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) && (num >= 0)) {

            Main m = new Main(path, num);
            m.deleteFile(dir);
        }

    } else {
        throw new InvalidParameterException("OOPS!");
    }
}
```

}

It runs off a batch file the gives the command
   java -cp . MainCopy "C:\Black" 5

the 5 controls how many days etc over to then delete, this is perfect.

However, i need it to delete just files on a server 2008. The files needed to be over 30 days so. java -cp . MainCopy "C:\Black" 30. However when this command is ran it deletes all the files in the folder.

Comment: It seems like it would make more sense just to write a batch file or powershell script rather than using Java for this.

Comment: I considered just using a batch in the beginning but there was limited functionality on the 2001 to do it, so i then created this java file. Maybe it would be easier on a 2008 server to do a batch.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days

Comment: Thank you, I have used that instead and it works. However I am still curious why the x amount of days parameter in my java code just stopped working. :|

Comment: Update the code and the community will be more of help