# Batch file to delete files 'older than N days' 'of specific types' 'contain specific words in filename'

Tags: batch-file

i'm strugling to create a Batch file sript to: 
- delete files
  - 'older than N days' 
  - 'of specific filetypes' 
  - 'contain specific words in filename'

For examle i want to delete files from path "c:\test"
 - older than 30 days
 - that are type of ".dmp" and ".log"
 - and they contain the words "aaa" or "bbb" in the filename.

I've tried some variation of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days) but didn't succeed.

Comment: Some hints to delete files older than N days can be found at http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-delolder.html. I am using their method 3) successfully.

Comment: Yes indeed, but i want certain filetypes and filenames..and i can't put all that arguments in search mask of  "forfiles /m.."

Comment: Where is the proplem? Simply use `forfiles` command 4 times to delete all files older than 30 days with the patterns `*aaa*.dmp`, `*bbb*.dmp`, `*aaa*.log` and `*bbb*.log` in your batch file.

Comment: I've Never thought it like that..! i was stack with the for command..
Thanks #mofi i used forfiles 4 times and worked..

Answer (score 1):

The following deletes files from directory `C:\test`, which match the pattern `*aaa*.dmp` and are at least 30 days old.

```
forfiles /P "C:\test" /M "*aaa*.dmp" /D -30 /C "cmd /C del @path"
```

Subdirectories are not searched; if you want that too add switch `/S`.