# Phalcon : temp directory

Tags: php, phalcon

I have created a folder with "temp" name, i resize images and save in this folder as temporary files, now, this files should be remove after some days, my mean is `Phalcon` should remove each data in this folder after 7 days from that created date.how should i implement it in `Phalcon` framework?

Comment: Why not delete the temporary files as part of the resize & save process, rather than just leaving garbage around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is outside the scope of Phalcon.

You should use a cron job (or equivalent) to run a script that will delete the files base on their creation date.

[Batch file to delete files older than N days (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51069/3935089)

[Delete files older than x days on linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/)