# LIST (not delete!) directories older than X using command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to get a list of directories older than 90 days from 'today's' date using windows command line so I can schedule a batch file to run these folders through a separate process.

I need to list folders and subfolders only, no files.

I have tried using '`dir`' which produces the list I need:

```
dir /b /s /a:d /o:gen >C:\file_list.txt
```

But, I can't check for dates greater than X using '`dir`'.

I've looked at using '`forfiles`' but this won't produce the list as I need it which my dir attempt produces.

To add some more complexity, ideally I need to check the date on the files within a folder rather than the folders date properties.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please read the tag info before you add tags! [tag:dos] and [tag:ms-dos] do definitely not apply here are `forfiles` was introduced in Windows...

Comment: What do you want exactly: a list of directories, or a list of files? is the sort order relevant?

Comment: Related: [Batch file to delete files older than N days](http://stackoverflow.com/a/51069)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you try with `Forfiles` like that :

```
@echo off
set OLD=90
FORFILES /S /D -%OLD% /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE echo @path"
pause
```

For more information about **[Forfiles command](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)**