# Create File with current Date in Filename + Robocopy logging

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, robocopy

Having very little experience with Batchfiles, scripting and generally "coding", I quickly ran into a problem with a Batch I want to create.

The situation is as follows:

I have a folder, in which *.txt files are automatically inserted, and I wanted to move these files to different folders based on the names the files have. I did this with Robocopy and it works just fine. Then I discovered the possibility to log the stuff that Robocopy does.
The Batch currently looks like this:

```
robocopy C:\Source C:\Target_Normal file*.txt /xf file022*.txt /mov /log+:LogNo.txt /ns /nc /np /r:1 /w:5
robocopy C:\Source C:\Target_Special file022*.txt /mov /log+:LogNo.txt /ns /nc /np /r:1 /w:3
```

This Batch has to be part of a Windows Scheduled Task, that has to run every Minute. Because there are a lot of files to be moved, the logfile will soon be very bloated. I now need a Logfile for every day, that the same Batch automatically creates the first time it runs on a new day. It would be perfect if the name of the newly created Logfile contained the Date it was created, of course. I want to put all of this above the robocopy lines.
In pseudocode, I'd like to have something like this:

```
If currentDay has no Logfile yet -> 
  Create Logfile with Name Log+currentDate  -> 
else (nothing and continue?)
```

...if that makes any sense. I just don't know how to express that to work in a Batch.

Comment: I think Robocopy will create the log if does not exist, so assemble the date in your preferred format and put it in a var.

Comment: Take a look at [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/) Another hint: use the Stack Overflow search with the search term `[batch-file] date time file name`. And see also the answer on [How to delete log file after a week?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38998531/3074564) It is much better to focus on log file size and not on age of log files because the available storage media size is the real limiting factor and not how old a file is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch demonstrates how to get the actual date with wmi and it splits that ISO date time into parts you can assemble to your liking.

```
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:: Get Local date time 
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=.+-" %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
    ) do Set _DT=%%A
Set "_yy=%_DT:~0,4%" & Set "_MM=%_DT:~4,2%"  & Set "_dd=%_DT:~6,2%"
Set "_hh=%_DT:~8,2%" & Set "_nn=%_DT:~10,2%" & Set "_ss=%_DT:~12,2%"
:: Put your date time elements together
::            %_DT:~0,8%  is yyyyMMdd
Set LogNo=Log_%_DT:~0,8%.txt
set _

Echo Logfile is : %LogNo%
Pause

robocopy C:\Source C:\Target_Normal file*.txt /xf file022*.txt /mov /log+:%LogNo% /ns /nc /np /r:1 /w:5
robocopy C:\Source C:\Target_Special              file022*.txt /mov /log+:%LogNo% /ns /nc /np /r:1 /w:3
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, this works perfect, thank you very much!