# How To Delete Folder, Sub-folder and files Automatically X days older on a network shared Drive

Tags: batch-file, networking, scheduled-tasks

I have a Western Digital 4 TB Cloud. My CCTV footage record on it. till now i delete those footage manually  when 4 TB becomes full. is there any way to write a script to delete the video footage 30 days older automatically by task scheduler.

Comment: you could use windows service to delete files. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/deleting-a-file-after-7-days-using-windows-services

Comment: does the file/directory-naming sheme include the date,and how?

Comment: `forfiles /S /P "C:\what\ever" /M "*.*" /D -30 /C "cmd /C del @path"` Unfortunately this does not support *UNC paths*, but works ok on local or mapped drives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file to delete files older than N days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)