# Automatically delete folder contents after 'n' days - Windows 10

Tags: batch-file, automation, windows-10, delete-file

I am wondering if someone can tell me how I can make a folder in windows that will automatically delete any files within that have been there for more than 'n' days, say maybe 7 for a week.

I have found a similar question that was answered well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days), though im not sure if it works on windows 10.  Also, would this be a '.bat' file? And, how do I make the batch file run automatically?

Thanks!

Edit:  I created a .bat file, starting with the mentioned answer:

```
forfiles /p "C:\what\ever" /s /m *.* /D -<number of days> /C "cmd /c del 
@path"
```

Which I changed to:

```
forfiles /p "F:\Movies" /s /m *.* /D -<1> /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

exactly, to test it.  The folder 'Movies' has a bunch of things whos date modified is from very long ago.  I created a task with Task Scheduler (Thanks Thomas)  and it didnt delete anything.

I also tried running the batch manually, tried changing it to 1 minute, tried putting it in the folder that its deleting from, and ran it as admin.  Nothing worked.  I have permissions on the folder.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Did I do something wrong with the code?

Comment: "Not sure if it works" - have you tried?

Comment: Have you heard about a tool called "Task scheduler"?

Comment: I don't know how to make the batch file run automatically though, so I wouldnt be able to test it.

Comment: For testing, you can just double click it. No need to run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I interpreted the command incorrectly.  `forfiles /p "F:\Movies" /s /m *.* /D -<1> /C "cmd /c del @path"` should have been `forfiles /p "F:\Movies" /s /m *.* /D -1 /C "cmd /c del @path"`, where the - is -1 , not -<1>.  Thanks to the helpful comments, I was able to do what I wanted, using the task scheduler to run this, now working, script.  Thanks.