# Delete old file AND LOG IT

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm looking for an easy batch script that will allow me to delete old files and log what it had delete or not. After searching the web I found "forfiles" really usefull:

```
forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.* -d <number of days> -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

from:
[Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

My concern like i said is to log what has been deleted. I tried lots of things but it still doesn't work. Here is my actual code:

```
set logfile=D:\what\ever\automatic_delete_log_%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%_%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%.txt
forfiles /p "C:\what\ever\Downloads" /s /m *.* /D -290 /C "cmd /c set status=failed; del @path && set status=success; echo @path @fdate %status% >> %logfile%"
echo %logfile%
```

The log file is created but is empty, and the old files are not removed. (It should remove the 8 files i have from 2016) When i use the original code it removes the files. I read it might about escaping the &&. I tried to escape them, I tried to escape the ; and i tried to escape both of them without more success. I'm out of idea about what  I should do. Can someone help?

The ojectiv is to delete the file, if it succeeds log "path, date, success" otherwise log "path, date, fail".

Comment: Remember that && will only run the next command if the previous command was successful (ie. ERRORLEVEL EQU 0).

Comment: ...and you don't string two lines together with a semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sufficient escaping, it can be done. Ugly, but can be done. Remember that the `DEL` command does -not- set `ERRORLEVEL`. A test for the file's existence would indicate that it has not successfully been deleted.

```
forfiles /p "C:\src\t" /s /m *.* /D -290 /C ^"cmd.exe /C ^
    set ^"status=failed^" ^&^& ^
    echo DEL @path ^&^& ^
    IF NOT EXIST @path ( ^
        echo @path @fdate SUCCESSFUL >>^"%logfile%^" ^
    ) ELSE ( ^
        echo @path @fdate FAILED >>^"%logfile%^" ^
    ) ^
    ^"
```

Comment: Ok, so even more escaping, even the ". And thank to point that DEL doesn't trigger errors. Gonna test it today. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working for some file in the log that didn't exist, i don't why, but you solved my issue, the files that should be removed are removed :)