# Cron Job to auto delete folder older than 7 days in Centos

Tags: linux, bash, cron, centos, filesystems

I have a folder with large files in centos and how to delete the files older than 30 minutes.

Please suggest your ideas and snippets

Comment: i would like to delete every 30 minutes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

Comment: How is this related to both *Linux* and *Windows ba**tc**h file*? Do you mean by **bash**?

Comment: yes bash files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. just use `find` and add the following line in`crontab`:

```
30 * * * * find /path/to/dir -type f -mmin +30 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

the above command will run every 30 minutes and delete ONLY files older that 30 minutes from the directory `/path/to/dir`