# CMD delete files older than X days in specific folders

Tags: batch-file, file-io, cmd, windows-7, del

I have few folders where I want to use a CMD file to delete files older than X days.

> C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationA\Data\Luke\Temp
>   C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationA\Data\Luke\Log
>   C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationA\Data\Padme\Temp
>   C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationA\Data\Padme\Log
>   C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationA\Data\Han\Temp
>   C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationA\Data\Han\Log
>
> C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationB\Data\Leia\Temp
>   C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationB\Data\Leia\Log
>   C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationB\Data\Padme\Temp
>   C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationB\Data\Padme\Log
>   C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationB\Data\Anakin\Temp
>   C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationB\Data\Anakin\Log
>
> C:\AwesomeSoftware\AppC\Data\Luke\Log
>
> C:\AwesomeSoftware\AppC\Data\Luke\Temp

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51069/1008588) answer I get the following working code for a specific path (and its subfolders), where X=30 days:

```
forfiles /p "C:\AwesomeSoftware\ApplicationA\Data\Luke" /s /m *.* /D -30 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

My question is: how can I modify the code to use it for some different folders but with the same structure.

As you can see the path is always a concatenation of `"C:\AwesomeSoftware\" + <name of application> + "\Data\" + <username> + "\Log" + <subfolder name>`.
While `<name of application>` can be 10-20 discrete values, the `<username>` list is very long (100-200).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody answered me but I've found the solution at the problem..

I post the snippet, maybe it will be useful for somebody.

```
for /d %%a in (C:\AwesomeSoftware\*) do (
    for /d %%x in (%%a\Data\*) do (forfiles /p "%%x\Temp" /s /m *.* /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @path")
)
```

Comment: can you explain the variables please so we can follow along?

Comment: A and x are part or the path. It matches any of C:\AwesomeSoftware\%%a\Data\%%x\Temp