# How to delete files end with a substring and older than N days

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to `delete` extensionless files older than `7` days whose names end with `_C`.

Example files:

> ```
> B_C_A1_C
> B_C_A2_C
> B_C_A3_A
> test.txt
> ```

My code:

```
SET mypath=%cd%\downloads
ForFiles /p %mypath% /d -7 /c "cmd /c del /q %mypath%\*_C
```

When I execute the code, it deletes all files which contains `_C`, but I want to delete only files which end with `_C` and are older than `7` days.

How can I fix this?

Comment: for ideas on how to assess files of a certain age, take a look here: `https://pastebin.com/F4yUs8Bq`

As for deleting files ending with _C, for the options in the for Loop, Make use of the Wildcard to define the set. `For /R %%A in (*_C.*) Do (`

Comment: Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `forfiles /?` to read its usage information. You'll note from that information that you can provide your searchmask `*_C`, using the `/M` option you have missed from your provided example! When you're there also please take a look at the various `@` variables, so that you can correct  your `/C` command. _Please also learn to doublequote your paths, as standard practice._

Comment: Thank you for help, but i imply your code like this:      SET mypath=%cd%
ForFiles /p %mypath% /d -7 /c "cmd /c For /R %%A in (*_c.*) Do (del /q @FILE)"      it keeps file whose names end with '_c' but it delete all files which are older than 7 days. How can i prevent this?  I just wanna delete files whose name end with '_C' and older then 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

For more information about the [forfiles documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles), see [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days?rq=1).

The wildcard expression `*_C` selects any files which end with `_C`, regardless of whether it has an extension.

The final code is insanely complicated:

```
forfiles /p "%cd%" /m *_C /C "cmd /c \"echo @file^|find \".\" ^|^| del @path\""
```

Using `*_C` will select the following:

```
anything without periods_C
```

It will **NOT** select the following:

```
any.thing_C
anything.txt._C
anything containing periods_C
```

Comment: @Compo Your edit was not what I meant. Using `*_C` **WILL** select files like `anything.txt._C`

Comment: HackingAddict0302, if I have modified anything you said, in a way which detracts from your intent, please feel free to correct it, it's your answer. However please note that your answer stated that "This code", "`_C`", "will delete the following files: `anything without periods_C`". That seemed wrong to me, as my interpretation is that, `_C` would select only files and directories named exactly `_C` or `_c`, nothing else.