# How can I generate a list of files with their absolute path in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, absolute-path, ls

I am writing a shell script that takes file paths as input.

For this reason, I need to generate recursive file listings with full paths. For example, the file `bar` has the path:

```
/home/ken/foo/bar
```

but, as far as I can see, both `ls` and `find` only give relative path listings:

```
./foo/bar   (from the folder ken)
```

It seems like an obvious requirement, but I can't see anything in the `find` or `ls` man pages.

How can I generate a list of files in the shell including their absolute paths?

Comment: use: `find /home/ken/foo/bar -exec ls -ld $PWD/{} \;`

Answer (score 414, accepted):

If you give `find` an absolute path to start with, it will print absolute paths. For instance, to find all .htaccess files in the current directory:

```bash
find "$(pwd)" -name .htaccess
```

or if your shell expands `$PWD` to the current directory:

```bash
find "$PWD" -name .htaccess
```

`find` simply prepends the path it was given to a relative path to the file from that path.

[Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) also suggested using `pwd -P` if you want to resolve symlinks in your current directory.

Comment: Note that if you also want to resolve symlinks, use `pwd -P`.

Comment: This is helpful, but I think user431529's response below is more valid:

`ls -d -1 $PWD/**/*` but I guess `find $PWD` also works (tested in bash)

Comment: @Brian Why? `find $PWD` is simple. The `ls` incantation is complex and unwieldy (unless you alias it). `find` is not dependent on shell glob expansions, so will work in any shell. `find` is also a lot more flexible, I can get a recursive listing of all files, or perhaps of all directories, or maybe I want a listing of all xml files, or all files changed in the last week. All that is possible with `find`, but not easily with `ls`.

Comment: I had to use `find "\`pwd\`" -name .htaccess` because of spaces in directory names

Comment: I don't get it, this command does not give me the absolute path of the file I, while other answers down on the list does the job.

Comment: Running a Debian/Turnkey Linux that i login to by putty, and using the exact command mentioned above. It returns the relative link to the file.

Comment: @Bjørn: Copy/paste? What does `pwd` output? I used it as an example, but as long as you give `find` an absolute path it should output absolute paths.

Comment: for me, I need `*.htaccess` to get all `.htaccess` files. (bash > 4)

Answer (score 262):

```
readlink -f filename
```

gives the full absolute path. But if the file is a symlink, you'll get the final resolved name.

Comment: Nice. Does not work on the BSD Variant of readlink (i.e Mac).I use gnucoreutils on mac. And hence can use greadlink which works with the above solution.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus - For Mac OS X, use `realpath` instead

Comment: if you install bash tools via `brew install coreutils`, then the executable will be installed as `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/readlink`

Comment: @sheki As of October 2023, on **macOS** Sonoma, `readlink -f` works without a problem "out of the box", i.e. no need for GNU `coreutils`.

Answer (score 178):

Use this for dirs (the `/` after `**` is needed in bash to limit it to directories):

```
ls -d -1 "$PWD/"**/
```

this for files and directories directly under the current directory, whose names contain a `.`:

```
ls -d -1 "$PWD/"*.*
```

this for everything:

```
ls -d -1 "$PWD/"**/*
```

Taken from here
  http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2002/msg00033.html

In bash, `**` is recursive if you enable `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: ls -d -1 $PWD/**/* does not recurse. Wish I could take my +1 back. You can do ** for each depth you need to go though.

Comment: The ** operator is a recursive globbing operator.  If you use the command in a shell that supports it (such as zsh), it will work properly.

Comment: ls -d1 "$PWD/"{\*,.\*} to also catch the hidden (dot) files.
For me the recursive version in the answer didn't prepend the absolute path to files in subfolders.

Comment: I think I'll have to use find... I get -> bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long

Comment: ls -altd ../{path}/**/* is my preference when recursing on all subdirs

Answer (score 53):

You can use

```
find $PWD
```

in bash

Comment: That will give the path of the current directory, and all the files and directories below it, as well. That's probably not what people are looking for.

Answer (score 38):

```
ls -d "$PWD/"*
```

This looks only in the *current* directory.  It quotes "$PWD" in case it contains spaces.

Comment: This is still a very valid answer, but it would be good to include the info that this does not work recursively (which is what I was looking for in fact!)

Comment: For recursive use: find . -exec ls -ld $PWD/{} \;

Comment: `ls` receives the files as its arguments when done like this as a glob, which works (not efficient but is simple to use and remember), but if looking at a huge directory, then it can cause an "argument list too long" error.

Answer (score 16):

**Command:** `ls -1 -d "$PWD/"*`

This will give the absolute paths of the file like below.

```
[root@kubenode1 ssl]# ls -1 -d "$PWD/"*
/etc/kubernetes/folder/file-test-config.txt
/etc/kubernetes/folder/file-test.txt
/etc/kubernetes/folder/file-client.txt
```

Answer (score 15):

You can do

```
ls -1 | xargs realpath
```

If you need to specify an absolute path or relative path, you can do that as well

```
ls -1 $FILEPATH | xargs realpath
```

Comment: `ls -1` is the default of piped `ls`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410557/537347

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
find "$PWD"/
```

You get **list of absolute paths** in working directory.

Comment: Does not work if $PWD contains space..:)

Answer (score 10):

The `$PWD` is a good option by Matthew above. If you want find to only print files then you can also add the  -type f option to search only normal files. Other options are "d" for directories  only etc. So in your case it would be (if i want to search only for files with .c ext):

```
find $PWD -type f -name "*.c"
```

or if you want all files:

```
find $PWD -type f
```

Note: You can't make an alias for the above command, because $PWD gets auto-completed to your home directory when the alias is being set by bash.

Comment: Actually, -d doesn't mean only directories - it means it treats directories like files.  So if you ls -d /home, you'll get back "/home", not a listing of what's in /home.

Comment: @Travis: he was talking about the option to find, not ls. In his case "find / -type d" would find only directories - as he said.

Answer (score 8):

If you give the find command an absolute path, it will spit the results out with an absolute path.  So, from the Ken directory if you were to type:

```
find /home/ken/foo/ -name bar -print
```

(instead of the relative path `find . -name bar -print`)

You should get:

```
/home/ken/foo/bar
```

Therefore, if you want an `ls -l` and have it return the absolute path, you can just tell the find command to execute an `ls -l` on whatever it finds.

```
find /home/ken/foo -name bar -exec ls -l {} ;\
```

NOTE: There is a space between `{}` and `;`

You'll get something like this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 ken admin       181 Jan 27 15:49 /home/ken/foo/bar
```

If you aren't sure where the file is, you can always change the search location.  As long as the search path starts with "/", you will get an absolute path in return.  If you are searching a location (like /) where you are going to get a lot of permission denied errors, then I would recommend redirecting standard error so you can actually see the find results:

```
find / -name bar -exec ls -l {} ;\ 2> /dev/null
```

(`2>` is the syntax for the Borne and Bash shells, but will not work with the C shell.  It may work in other shells too, but I only know for sure that it works in Bourne and Bash).

Comment: You can pass multiple args to the same `ls` process with `-exec ls -ld {} +`.  (You probably want `-d` to not have `ls` list directory contents).  Or better, use find's built-in `ls` with `find ... name bar -ls`.  Also, you have the syntax wrong for one arg per command: you have to quote the semicolon from the shell, so it's `{} \;`.

Answer (score 7):

Just an alternative to

```
ls -d "$PWD/"*
```

to pinpoint that `*` is shell expansion, so

```
echo "$PWD/"*
```

would do the same (the drawback you cannot use `-1` to separate by new lines, not spaces).

Comment: can you elaborate more on this? what is a shell expansion? how to use `-1` to separete by lines?

Comment: @Antonio Araujo, shell expansion is the shell (e.g. bash) will replace * with list of files - can read more on bash man page. -1 is ls command option, echo is other command, it does not have same options.

Answer (score 6):

If you need list of all files in current as well as sub-directories

```
find $PWD -type f
```

If you need list of all files only in current directory

```
find $PWD -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Answer (score 5):

#### [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)

Using `fd` (alternative to `find`), use the following syntax:

```
fd . foo -a
```

Where `.` is the search pattern and `foo` is the root directory.

E.g. to list all files in `etc` recursively, run: `fd . /etc -a`.

> `-a`, `--absolute-path`     Show absolute instead of relative paths

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this.

```sh
for name in /home/ken/foo/bar/*
do
    echo $name
done
```

You can get abs path using `for` loop and `echo` simply without `find`.

Answer (score 2):

find jar file recursely and print absolute path

```
ls -R |grep "\.jar$" | xargs readlink -f
```

```bash
/opt/tool/dev/maven_repo/com/oracle/ojdbc/ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar
/opt/tool/dev/maven_repo/com/oracle/ojdbc/ons-19.3.0.0.jar
/opt/tool/dev/maven_repo/com/oracle/ojdbc/oraclepki-19.3.0.0.jar
/opt/tool/dev/maven_repo/com/oracle/ojdbc/osdt_cert-19.3.0.0.jar
/opt/tool/dev/maven_repo/com/oracle/ojdbc/osdt_core-19.3.0.0.jar
/opt/tool/dev/maven_repo/com/oracle/ojdbc/simplefan-19.3.0.0.jar
/opt/tool/dev/maven_repo/com/oracle/ojdbc/ucp-19.3.0.0.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

This works best if you want a dynamic solution that works well in a function

```
lfp ()
{
  ls -1 $1 | xargs -I{} echo $(realpath $1)/{}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lspwd() { for i in $@; do ls -d -1 $PWD/$i; done }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that prints out a list without an extra period and that also demonstrates how to search for a file match.  Hope this helps:

```
find . -type f -name "extr*" -exec echo `pwd`/{} \; | sed "s|\./||"
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. But it didn't list in alphabetical order.

```
find "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 1
```

This command lists alphabetically as well as lists hidden files too.

```
ls -d -1 "$PWD/".*; ls -d -1 "$PWD/"*;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `stat`

Absolute path of a single file:

```
stat -c %n "$PWD"/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give the canonical path (will resolve symlinks): `realpath FILENAME`

If you want canonical path to the symlink itself, then: `realpath -s FILENAME`

Answer (score 1):

Most if not all of the suggested methods result in paths that cannot be used directly in some other terminal command if the path contains spaces. Ideally the results will have slashes prepended.
This works for me on macOS:

```
find / -iname "*SEARCH TERM spaces are okay*" -print 2>&1  | grep -v denied |grep -v permitted |sed -E 's/\ /\\ /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
for p in <either relative of absolute path of the directory>/*; do
    echo $(realpath -s $p)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive files can be listed by many ways in Linux. Here I am sharing one liner script to clear all logs of files(only files) from `/var/log/` directory and second check recently which logs file has made an entry.

First:

```
find /var/log/ -type f  #listing file recursively
```

Second:

```
for i in $(find $PWD -type f) ; do cat /dev/null > "$i" ; done #empty files recursively
```

Third use:

```
ls -ltr $(find /var/log/ -type f ) # listing file used in recent
```

Note: for directory location you can also pass `$PWD` instead of `/var/log`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have symbolic links, you could try

```sh
tree -iFL 1 [DIR]
```

`-i` makes tree print filenames in each line, without the tree structure.

`-f` makes tree print the full path of each file.

`-L 1` avoids tree from recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Write one small function

```
lsf() {
ls `pwd`/$1
}
```

Then you can use like

```
lsf test.sh
```

it gives full path like

```
/home/testuser/Downloads/test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to list absolute path of files in a directory in a txt file:

```bash
find "$PWD" -wholename '*.JPG' >test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter, more convenient solution:

```bash
find ~+
```

- `~+` means `"$PWD"`, except it's quoted automatically, and requires less reaching around the keyboard for symbols
- Add `-name .htaccess` or `-maxdepth 1` if necessary

Unlike what another answer says, you CAN make an alias for this command:

```bash
alias fa='find ~+'
```

- Put this in `~/.bashrc` and you only have to type as little as 2 letters
- Alternatively you can add `-name` at the end of the alias and use it like `fa .htaccess`
- The single quotes prevent premature expansion
- fa means Find Absolute path

Answer (score -1):

```
ls -1 | awk  -vpath=$PWD/ '{print path$1}'
```