# Bash script for outputting directory details to a file

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a simple bash script that will search for files with a certain extension in a directory.  Then output all those files with full path in front.

For example, if I have a directory with many different file types, but I want to know the information about those with only the .txt extension.  How can I get the output in a new file to look similar to this:

```
/home/jason/code/test1.txt
/home/jason/code/test2.txt
.
.
.
```

All I have right now is this, which is not really what I am trying to do, but it is just my attempt at experimentation because I am new:

```
ls *.txt >prog_list.txt
pwd >pwd.txt
cat pwd.txt prog_list.txt > prog_dir.txt
```

Comment: asked a different way, but a nearly a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /home/jason/code -iname "*.txt" > prog_dir.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that it will work in any directory when the script is run?  Kind of like "find pwd -iname "*.txt" > prog_dir.txt"

Comment: Yep.  `find \`pwd\` -iname "*.txt" > prog_dir.txt`  Notice the backticks around pwd.

Comment: Ahh, thats why it wasn't working..  Feels good that I was close at least.

Thanks Amar

Comment: You can just do `find . -iname '*.txt' > prog_dir.txt`

Comment: @Daenyth - That would not put the full path in the output file.

Comment: @newbie_dev - No habla ventanas!  Seriously, though, I'm not as fluent with cmd.exe as I am with bash.  Perhaps if you asked it as a separate question and tagged it Windows you'd attract some great responses.

Comment: @Amardeep, ah right. In that case I'd just do `locate .txt` if you need full paths... That won't anchor the search though.

Comment: Use `find "$PWD" -iname '*.txt'`—note the quotes, otherwise it wouldn't work with directory names containing spaces. Also note that it won't work with file names containing newlines.

Answer (score 1):

`find ~/code -name '*.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$>find -name "*.yourext" > myFile.txt
```

For more information on the find command, type:

```
$>man find
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like:

```
find . -name *.txt -print
```

do the trick?