# linux releative path to fullpath file name

Tags: linux, bash

I need a way of getting the fullpath name of a file on a linux shell script.
The full path may already be supplied or a relative file may be supplied.

```
afile.txt 
/home/me/bfile.txt
```

to

```
/home/me/afile.txt
/home/me/bfile.txt
```

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I list files with their absolute path in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux)

Answer (score 7):

Use readlink(1).

```
readlink -f afile
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack:

```
get_fn()
{
  echo $(cd $(dirname $1); pwd)/$(basename $1)
}
```

But it can be costly.

Answer (score 0):

If the directory will be the same, you can list the files in that directory in this way:

```
DIRECTORY=/some/directory
FILE_NAME="my-file-list"

for i in `ls -1 $DIRECTORY`
 do 
   echo $i >> $FILE_NAME
done
```

Otherwise, you would use the `FIND` command in the [How can I list files with their absolute path in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux)

Comment: `ls` is not needed. `for i in "$DIRECTORY"/*`