# cp: cannot stat; using dirname to parse pathname and copy files

Tags: bash, function, grep, ubuntu-14.04, cp

--

I need to copy each file which a process has open, by reading its file descriptor in the `/proc/[pid]/fd/` directory etc. more specifically I need to find the directory of the file for each `pid`, then egrep for a regex; files ending in `[0-9]$`. cp throws an exception:

> cp: cannot stat ‘poop.log.2016-01-08T12-34-10’: No such file or directory

```
function foo {
    local f
    logfile="$(logfile_for_pid)" # calls the function to get file descriptor
    for f in "$logfile"; do
            for i in "$(dirname "$f")"; do
                    echo "ls the dirname: "$i""
                    ls "$i" | egrep -e '[0-9]$' | xargs cp -t /tmp
            done
    done
}
```

My question would be: how do I pass the `ls` output as an argument for `cp`?

also; running directly from the terminal. same error! note; I am new to bash!

```
$ cp `ls "$dir" | egrep -e '[0-9]$'` /tmp
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It seems `ls "$dir"` would just list the file names in the directory, not the full path. `find` may be a better option here. See eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux

Comment: @Evert thank you! `find "$PWD"` done the trick.

Comment: @ByronGrogan You should read [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) ... same goes to just replacing it with `find` here.

Comment: Why do you loop over `"$logfile"`?   The loop could only ever run one iteration -- are you trying to avoid running it when the output is empty, or is this just completely redundant?

Comment: Looks like `cp -t /tmp "$(dirname "$f")"/*[0-9]` would accomplish what you are spending several lines of pretzel logic to try to do.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a race condition -- the file exists when you read the directory, but is removed by the time the `cp` runs.  There really isn't any way to avoid that, but you can reduce the time window to make it less likely to happen, or perhaps stop the other process which is meddling with the symlinks for the duration of the copy operation.

Answer (score 1):

There will very seldom be a reason to pipe the output of the `ls` utility to anything.

I'm looking at you code thinking that the outermost loop (with `f`) is most likely unnecessary, since anything you store in `$logfile` will be treated as a single file name in any case (`for f in "$logfile"`).

This cuts it down to

```
function foo {
    logfile="$(logfile_for_pid)"

    for i in "$(dirname "$logfile")"; do
        echo "ls the dirname: "$i""
        ls "$i" | egrep -e '[0-9]$' | xargs cp -t /tmp
    done
}
```

The inner loop may be eliminated, because we know there's only one `$logfile`:

```
function foo {
    logfile="$(logfile_for_pid)"

    i="$(dirname "$logfile")"
    echo "ls the dirname: "$i""

    ls "$i" | egrep -e '[0-9]$' | xargs cp -t /tmp
}
```

And now you'd like to copy all files with a digit at the end of their filenames in that directory to `/tmp`:

```
function foo {
    logfile="$(logfile_for_pid)"

    i="$(dirname "$logfile")"
    echo "ls the dirname: "$i""

    cp "$i"/*[0-9] /tmp
}
```

Or did I misunderstand you?