# How to find certain file's full path using shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I get a problem, in my Ubuntu, I work in the directory like `/local/jenkins/scripts`, there are many sub-directories here, and I want to get all of the excute.sh file in the directories, but you may know, if I use "`find -name excute.sh`", it will return the list of relative paths, like following.

```
./TEST933/excute.sh
./TEST923/excute.sh
./TEST323/excute.sh
./TEST920/excute.sh
```

Can you please share how to get the full path list as below? Thanks!

```
/local/jenkins/scripts/TEST933/excute.sh
/local/jenkins/scripts/TEST923/excute.sh
/local/jenkins/scripts/TEST323/excute.sh
/local/jenkins/scripts/TEST920/excute.sh
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list files with their absolute path in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with readlink ;

```
find -name excute.sh -exec readlink -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this;

```
find /local/jenkins/scripts/ -name excute.sh
```

eg;

```
$ find -name excute.sh
./TEST920/excute.sh
./TEST933/excute.sh
./TEST923/excute.sh
./TEST323/excute.sh

$ find /tmp/test/ -name excute.sh
/tmp/test/TEST920/excute.sh
/tmp/test/TEST933/excute.sh
/tmp/test/TEST923/excute.sh
/tmp/test/TEST323/excute.sh
```