# get the list of files hirarchically with its absolute path

Tags: list, awk, ls

I want the output as shown in below example.

```
root@aklinux139:~/.atom# du -sh */* | awk '{print $2}'
blob-store/BLOB
blob-store/INVKEYS
blob-store/MAP
compile-cache/less
compile-cache/root
compile-cache/style-manager
packages/README.md
storage/application.json
root@aklinux139:~/.atom#
```

But ls does not give this output with any of its options/arguments.
'`ls -R`' gives path and then its content not the filename with its absolute path.

I need this very often while writing scripts, Can someone help me with this ? Thanks heap in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list files with their absolute path in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find`, an example for a depth of 2 :

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -printf '%P\n'
```

If you want to exclude dot files :

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -not -path '*/\.*' -printf '%P\n'
```

If you want to sort the result (as `du -sh`) :

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -not -path '*/\.*' -printf '%P\n' | sort
```

Comment: Thank you so much this solution worked perfectly. Thanks a lot Bertrand :)

Comment: Glad to help, you can accept the answer if your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
find / -name "*" |head
/
/var
/var/games
/var/yp
/var/kerberos
/var/kerberos/krb5
/var/kerberos/krb5/user
/var/.updated
/var/nis
/var/account
```