# Find a file and export the full path to a list

Tags: linux, shell, find

I'm looking for a way to search certain files named "XYHello.pdf" or "BDHello.pdf" so basically "*Hello.pdf" in a directory with subfolder and export the found files including path to the file in a text file.

So that at the end I have a list with all found files including the paths in a list. I spontaneously thought about Linux Command find.

```
find . -type f -iname "*Hello.pdf"
```

But the problem is i need the full path to the file in a list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question, but about the use of a linux standard tool. As such it's best off at https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: that said: if you replace your `.` with `$PWD` `find` will  give you the full path ;)

Comment: Please allow us to Google that for you: [find file show full path](https://www.google.com/search?q=find+file+show+full+path). And then the first hit:  [How can I list files with their absolute path in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246215/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find $PWD -type f -iname "*Hello.pdf"
```

or

```
find . -type f -iname "*Hello.pdf" -exec realpath {} \;
```

Comment: For _MS-Windows_, the **answer** is _here_--[How to Export File Search Results to Excel](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/export-file-search-results-excel-40552.html)