# How to print all the file paths inside of a folder from linux command line

Tags: linux, path, command-line-interface

I have a very simple question about the linux command line. Say I'm in a folder in the terminal with 6 CSV files. I'd like to simply print out the contents of the folder with all of the paths to the six files listed. I'd like to use these paths to these files in my code to access them. What command would do this?

Would it be a modified LS command? I'd like to not use the 'find' command.

Comment: welcome to [so], a programmer's forum. this is a great place to ask questions when you got stuck. however, it is not an automated programming service, where you simply state your problem in human langugae and get a running program in return for free. what have you tried so far, were are you failing?

Comment: [Are you looking for something like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-generate-a-list-of-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show an example how the result should look like. Please explain *why* you don't want to use `find` which might be the ideal tool for this. It is not a good idea to print the file paths first and parse this output to access the files. You could do something like `for f in "$(pwd)"/*.csv; do do_something_with "$f"; done`