# remove old backup files

Tags: bash, shell

```
# find /home/shantanu -name 'my_stops*' | xargs ls -lt | head -2
```

The command mentioned above will list the latest 2 files having my_stops in it's name. I want to keep these 2 files. But I want to delete all other files starting with "my_stops" from the current directory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you create backups on a regular basis, it may be useful to use the -atime option of find so only files older than your last two backups can be selected for deletion.

For daily backups you might use

```
$ find /home/shantanu -atime +2 -name 'my_stops*' -exec rm {} \;
```

but a different expression (other than -atime) may suit you better.

In the example I used +2 to mean more than 2 days.

Comment: "2" means exactly two. If you want "older than" you need to use "+2".

Comment: Couldn't you also use "-delete"?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a non-recursive solution:

```
ls -t my_stops* | awk 'NR>2 {system("rm \"" $0 "\"")}'
```

Explanation:

- The ls command lists files with the latest 2 on top
- The awk command states that for those lines (NR = number of records, i.e. lines) greater than 2, delete them
- The quote characters are needed just in case the file names have embedded spaces

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash)

`(ls -t|head -n 2;ls)|sort|uniq -u|xargs rm`

Answer (score 1):

That will show you from the second line forward ;)

find /home/shantanu -name 'my_stops*' | xargs ls -lt | tail -n +2

Just keep in mind that find is recursive ;)

Comment: You can use `-maxdepth` to control recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Without recursive approach:

```
find /home/folder/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -mtime +2
```

Comment: Can you give some comments to the OP to explain what you're doing and why?