# Bash command to delete all but last 5 directories

Tags: bash, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete all but the most recent X files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash)

I have a script to create incremental backups daily and I need to delete all backups but last 5.

For example, I have this folders:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Oct 29 01:10 2010-10-29
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Oct 30 01:10 2010-10-30
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Oct 31 01:10 2010-10-31
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  1 01:10 2010-11-01
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  2 01:10 2010-11-02
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  3 01:10 2010-11-03
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  4 01:10 2010-11-04
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  5 01:10 2010-11-05
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  6 01:10 2010-11-06
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  7 01:10 2010-11-07
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  8 01:10 2010-11-08
```

And I need to maintain only the last 5 directories and delete the others. After command execute, I need to have only this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  4 01:10 2010-11-04
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  5 01:10 2010-11-05
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  6 01:10 2010-11-06
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  7 01:10 2010-11-07
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  8 01:10 2010-11-08
```

I don't need to delete previous to 5 days, I need to delete all except 5 last directories :)

Now I'm using:

`find /backup/increment -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

But I need to improved not based in time :)

**EDIT:** This is an example for a server that do backups all days, but I need an script that delete all folders previous to last 5 because my computer do backups at 00:10 at night, but not all nights the backup is done it, because my computer isn't working all days, and I need to have always the last 5 backups :)

Comment: If it's not "based in time", what is your definition of the "last 5"?

Comment: @dogbane thanks but the @MartinStettner solution seems to be more elegant solution :)

Comment: @David Added a comment in main post.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

use the `tail` command to print lines starting with the *n* th line (Option `-n +N`):

```
rm `ls -t | tail -n +6`
```

`ls -t` outputs the current directory sorted by time. `tail -n +6` takes al lines starting with the 6th line. Quoting with backticks feeds the result of the pipe into the `rm` command.

**OLD SOLUTION, not correct ...**

use the `head` command, which prints the first *n* lines of some output:

```
rm `ls -t1 | head -n 5`
```

`ls -t` outputs the current directory sorted by time. `head -n 5` takes the first five entries of the previous output. Quoting with backticks feeds the result of the pipe into the `rm` command.

Please try out first before applying to live data :) ...

Comment: You'd want to use tail instead, for the *last* n lines. But yeah, that solution is way simpler and better than mine. :)

Comment: What about: `rm $(ls | sort -r | sed 1,5d)`; list the names in date order; sort them into reverse order (most recent first); delete the first five lines; remove whatever is left.

Comment: @Max: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Fortunately, there is the +N option to `tail` (which I wasn't aware of), so we can get all lines *but the first n*.

Comment: @Jonathan: You have to use `ls -t` in order to get results sorted by time (or you have to relay on the files having correct names). You could also use `ls -t -r` to reverse the sorting, so `sort` is not needed.

Comment: @MartinStettner: given the naming convention used, there is no need for '-t'; indeed, it might even give the wrong results.  Suppose the directory for 2010-10-31 had been modified two days ago; then '`ls -t`' would give the wrong directory sequence.

Comment: @Jonathan: Partially agreed. But given the sample code (using `find`) in the question, Lito wanted the last five directories *based on time* to be retained. I hope that, reading these comments, he'll know which version to use :) ...

Comment: In case the command return empty result, we can prefer this syntax to avoid command error `ls -t | tail -n +6 | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that came to my mind. It's not elegant:

```
a=0;
for i in `ls -t`;
do
    a=`expr $a + 1`;
    if [ $a  -gt 5 ]; then
          echo "removing $i";
          rm -rf $i
    fi;
done
```

Comment: It's not elegant, but it's a possible solution :)

Answer (score 0):

create two dummy files with the start and the end date

```
touch -t 1010290000 before
touch -t 2011042359 after
```

find all the files between the 2 dummy files and "rm -rf" the result

```
find . -newer before \! -newer after -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Any more elegant solution? :)

Comment: The solution will not be based in date/time :)

Answer (score 0):

ls -tr | perl -ne '{@files = <>; print @files[0..$#files-5 ]}' | xargs -n1 echo rm -rf

You would remove the echo before the rm -rf to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The trick will be the -t option to ls, which sorts by modification time, from newest to oldest.

A really naive solution, using a temporary file, might go this way:

```
ls -t > /tmp/file_list
num_files_to_keep=5
# wc -l gets the line count of a file
# first word of wc output is the actual line count, and that's all we need, so
# delete everything after the space.
num_files=`wc -l /tmp/file_list | sed "s/ .*//"`
#if appropriate you should add a check for num_files < num_files_to_keep
num_files_to_delete=$(( $num_files - $num_files_to_keep ))
rm `tail -n $num_files_to_delete /tmp/file_list`
```