# Always keep n newest files in dir

Tags: bash, sorting, pipe, wc

I'm trying to create a one-liner which should remove excess files from dir to save it from consuming too much space.

```
ls -r --sort=time | head -${{ls | wc -l} - n} | xargs rm -f
```

n should stand for number of files I want to keep in directory.

I'm doing something wrong here and can't figure out what. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
( ls -t | head -n 25 ; ls ) | sort | uniq -u | sed -e 's,.*,"&",g' | xargs rm
```

Done the trick for me.

[Delete all but the most recent X files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash) <-- here

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

That `${{...}}` looks vaguely like TCL or something.  It is certainly not valid shell script.

In Bash (but not in Bourne shell) you can use `(( ... ))` for artithmetic expression, which I guess is what you want the "- n" to do.

The syntax for process substitution is `$(ls | wc -l)` with round parentheses.

Merging these two, you might end up with something like `(($(ls | wc -l) - n))` but you really [should not be parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) anyway.  Look at one of the many, many duplicates of this question for better approaches.