# Bash script to delete files in a directory if there are more than 5

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is a backup script that copies files from one directory to another.  I use a `for` loop to check if there are more than five files.  If there are, the loop should delete the oldest entries first.

I tried `ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm` from the command line and it works successfully to delete older files if there are more than 5 in the directory.

However, when I put it into my `for` loop, I get an error `rm: missing operand`

Here is the full script. I don't think I am using the `for` loop correctly in the script, but I'm really not sure how to use the commands `ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm` in a loop that iterates over the files in the directory.

```
timestamp=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
dest=${HOME}/mybackups
src=${HOME}/safe
fname='bu_'
ffname=${HOME}/mybackups/${fname}${timestamp}.tar.gz

# for loop for deletion of file
for f in ${HOME}/mybackups/*
do
  ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm
done

if [ -e $ffname ];
  then
      echo "The backup for ${timestamp} has failed." | tee ${HOME}/mybackups/Error_${timestamp}
  else
      tar -vczf ${dest}/${fname}${timestamp}.tar.gz ${src}
fi
```

**Edit: I took out the `for` loop, so it's now just:**

```
[...]
ffname=${HOME}/mybackups/${fname}${timestamp}.tar.gz

ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm

if [ -e $ffname ];
[...]
```

The script WILL work if it is in the `mybackups` directory, however, I continue to get the same error if it is not in that directory.  The script gets the file names but tries to remove them from the current directory, I think...  I tried several modifications but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Why do you need a for loop?

Comment: @John1024 pointed out that I don't need a loop and I took it out but I don't want to edit the code in the original question.  Please see comments below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get an error `rm: missing operand`

The cause of that error is that there are no files left to be deleted.  To avoid that error, use the `--no-run-if-empty` option:

```
ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm
```

In the comments, mklement0 notes that this issue is peculiar to GNU `xargs`.  BSD `xargs` will not run with an empty argument.  Consequently, it does not need and does not support the `--no-run-if-empty` option.

#### More

Quoting from a section of code in the question:

```
for f in ${HOME}/mybackups/*
do
  ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm
done
```

Note that (1) `f` is never used for anything and (2) this runs the `ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm` several times in a row when it needs to be run only once.

#### Obligatory Warning

Your approach parses the output of `ls`.  This makes for a simple and easily understood command.  It can work *if* all your files are sensibly named.  *It will not work in general.*  For more on this, see: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

### Safer Alternative

The following will work with all manner of file names, whether they contains spaces, tabs, newlines, or whatever:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %i\n' | sort -n | head -n -5 | while read tstamp inode
do
    find . -inum "$inode" -delete
done
```

Comment: ok I see what you are saying. So, I removed the for loop and just run the command in the script but now it finds the correct files but says it cannot remove them `cannot remove ‘6.txt’: No such file or directory` I don't think rm is working on the correct directory.

Comment: [What's the working directory of ls -tr?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/604110/bash-script-to-delete-files-in-a-directory-if-there-are-more-than-5#comment844104_604110)

Comment: @Cyrus `${HOME}/mybackups/`

Comment: @MichaelJames Is there an actual file in the directory named `6.txt`?  If a file in your directory has whitespace in its name, you will get errors like this (this why parsing ls is considered bad).

Comment: If there are more than 5 files in the directory, how many of the older files are you wanting to remove?

Comment: @MichaelJames: `ls`'s working directory is the directory from which you execute your script. If you execute your script from /tmp/foobar then `ls -tr` shows content of /tmp/foobar.

Comment: @John1024 yes that file is actually in the directory.  This is a contrived exercise, I'm really new to bash scripting.  However, the script is not run from that directory.

Comment: @ILostMySpoon All of them and the command `ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm` does that correctly

Comment: @MichaelJames "No such file or directory" That is odd. What type of filesystem is this file on? Is it an NFS share? Is it on a windows (NTFS) disk?  Also, I added an approach to the answer that does not make direct use of file names.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: @John1024 Hi John.  I tried your solution but it didn't work.  I'm running Ubuntu.  Still haven't figured it out unfortunately.

Comment: Nicely done. You probably meant `sort -nr`, not `sort -n`. "Consider:" confused me at first, because I thought it was a _recommendation_ rather than a critical analysis of the OP's code. As a minor point of interest: _BSD_ `xargs`  does _not_ run with empty input (and doesn't support `--no-run-if-empty`).

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks much.  I clarified the "consider" part and added your info on BSD `xargs`.  It may seem surprising (it was to me), but, when used with `head -n -5` as in the OP's code, `sort -n` is actually correct here.  (I verified this with tests.)   Alternatively, we could have used `sort -rn | tail -n +6` to the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for updating and for clarifying the `sort` issue; I had a misconception about what `head -n -5` does: it actually drops the _last_ 5 lines. (BSD  `head`, sadly, doesn't support this; there it can be emulated with `awk`: `awk -v n=5 '{l[NR]=$0; if (NR > n) {print l[NR-n]; delete l[NR-n]}}'`)

Answer (score 0):

SMH.  I ended up coming up to the simplest solution in the world by just `cd`-ing into the directory before I ran `ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm` .  Thanks for everyone's help!

```
timestamp=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
dest=${HOME}/mybackups
src=${HOME}/safe
fname='bu_'
ffname=${HOME}/mybackups/${fname}${timestamp}.tar.gz

cd ${HOME}/mybackups
ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm

if [ -e $ffname ];
  then
      echo "The backup for ${timestamp} has failed." | tee ${HOME}/mybackups/Error_${timestamp}
  else
      tar -vczf ${dest}/${fname}${timestamp}.tar.gz ${src}
fi
```

This line `ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm` came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash)

> ls -tr displays all the files, oldest first (-t newest first, -r
>   reverse).
>
> head -n -5 displays all but the 5 last lines (ie the 5 newest files).
>
> xargs rm calls rm for each selected file

.