# How to delete x old files in amazon s3 using amazon CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have found this regarding deletion of old files in bash:
[Delete all but the most recent X files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash)

I want the same functionality, however I cannot apply the same principles in my script as it is interacting with an amazon s3 directory.

Does anyone know how to use amazon CLI to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just create a lifecycle rule on S3 to delete older files. Then this process is done automatically for you.

Otherwise I guess you need to LIST all objects' metadata and write a script that checks if the script is old enough. But if you have a lot of objects this can be quite costly, while the lifecycle rule is free.