# Print the last saved screenshot with Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

This shows the last saved screenshot (on my Desktop path):

```
 ls -t | head -n1
```

This prints perfectly:

```
 lp -o -scaling=50 -o media=Custom.60x42mm -o page-left=0 -o page-right=0 -o page-top=5 -o page-bottom=5 image.png
```

How does one combine them?

Without really knowing what I'm doing I've tried this:

```
ls -t | head -n1 |awk '{lp -o -scaling=50 -o media=Custom.60x42mm -o page-left=0 -o page-right=0 -o page-top=5 -o page-bottom=5  $0}'
```

which, naturally fails:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lp -o -scaling=50 -o media=Custom.60x42mm -o page-left=0 -o page-right=0 -o page-top=5 -o page-bottom=5  "$(ls -t | head -n1)"
```

Or more clear:

```
filetouse="$(ls -t | head -n1)"
lpoptions=( -o -scaling=50 -o media=Custom.60x42mm -o page-left=0 -o page-right=0 -o page-top=5 -o page-bottom=5 )

lp "${lpoptions[@]}" "${filetouse}"
```

Comment: oh, this is more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just managed to do it.
This worked:

```
ls -t | head -n1 | xargs -I {} lp -o -scaling=50 -o media=Custom.60x42mm -o page-left=0 -o page-right=0 -o page-top=5 -o page-bottom=5 {}
```

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash).