# Deleting N files in bash where all but one filename are timestamps

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

Firstly yes, there are several versions of this question floating around this site, but I decided to ask because I haven't seen one with the specific caveat my problem has, and despite years of programming experience, I've never really *needed* bash before, so I don't have the practical knowledge to work this out myself.

I have an incremental backup script on Server A which uses rsync to copy over an SQL file. It syncs these to a folder called `sql/` to a file called `latest.sql`. This is all cron jobbed and works fine, but I need to implement a rotation on the destination Server B.

The last thing my script on Server A does is call the cleanup script on Server B. The cleanup script should do the following:

1. Get the current time using `NOWDT="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S')"` so it is in the form `2017-03-27_17_30_00`.
2. Copy `latest.sql` into `${NOWDT}.sql` using `cp` (same dir).

**(this is the tricky part I haven't solved yet)**

3. List the files alphabetically, so the timestamped ones should be above `latest.sql` (I want to keep this).
4. **If there are more than four files** (three timestamped **and** `latest.sql`), delete the top (earlier) ones until there are only three timestamped ones.

Once it's done there should be a maximum of 4 files in there: `latest.sql` and up to three timestamped ones.

I've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash) and there's some good stuff there but I just don't have enough knowledge of bash scripting to work out how to effectively modify it to suit my needs. Also I don't know how relevant it is but I'm using the standard bash shell that comes with CentOS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls [0-9]*.sql | sort | head -n -3 | xargs -r rm -f
```

1. list all files what started with digit and has extention .sql
2. sort it
3. remove first 3 lines (file what we want to keep)
4. remove all files what left. `xargs -r` get file names from input and run `rm -f <filenames>`. `-r` mean "not run if there is no input"

Comment: The form of `head -n -3` is GNU head only. Posix does not have that. You can use `tail -n 4` instead that will work on Posix and Linux / GNU

Comment: @komar : `sort` is not necessary. `ls` outputs the entries by default in a sorted way. Also, I would replace `ls` by echo. BTW, this would also yield the entries already sorted, because this is also the default for wildcard expansion.

Comment: What advantages does `echo` have over `ls`? Is there any technical reason one is better?