# bash rm to delete old files only deleting the first one

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

I found a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789/2847712) to delete everything but the 'n' newest files in a directory.

I modified it to this:

```
sudo rm /home/backup/`ls -t /home/backup/ | awk 'NR>5'`
```

It deletes only one file. It reports the following message about the rest of the files it should have deleted:

```
rm: cannot remove 'delete_me_02.tar': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'delete_me_03.tar': No such file or directory
...
```

I believe that the problem is the path. It's looking for delete_me_02.tar (and subsequent files) in the current directory, and it's somehow lost its reference to the correct directory.

How can I modify my command to keep looking in the /home/backup/ directory for all 'n' files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe find could help you do what you want:

```
find /home/backup -type f | xargs ls -t | head -n 5 | xargs rm
```

But I would first check what find would return (just remove `| xargs rm`) and check what is going to be removed.

Comment: find was the right answer. `find /home/backup/. -type f | xargs ls -t | tail -n+5 | xargs rm -f`

Comment: I believe this works because `find` returns the full path, I think that's a somewhat significant distinction.

Answer (score 1):

After the command substitution expands, your command line looks like

```
sudo rm /home/backup/delete_me_01.tar delete_me_02.tar delete_me_03.tar etc
```

`/home/backup` is not prefixed to each word from the output. (Aside: don't use `ls` in a script; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.)

Frankly, this is something most shells just doesn't make easy to do properly. (Exception: with `zsh`, you would just use `sudo rm /home/backup/*(Om[1,-6])`.) I would use some other language.

Answer (score 1):

The command in the backticks will be expanded to the list of relative file paths:

```
%`ls -t /home/backup/ | awk 'NR>5'`
a.txt b.txt c.txt ...
```

so the full command will now look like this:

```
sudo rm /home/backup/a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

which, I believe, makes it pretty obvious on why only the first file is removed.

There is also a limit on a number of arguments you can pass to `rm`, so 
you better modify your script to use `xargs` instead:

```
ls -t|tail -n+5|xargs -I{} echo rm /home/backup/'{}'
```

(just remove `echo`, once you verify that it produces an expected results for you)