# Find and delete directories except last 4 modified ones in linux

Tags: linux, bash, ls

To delete all the directories inside a folder except the last 4 modified folders in Linux, does the below command work?

```
find /path/folder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs ls -td -- | tail -n +5 | xargs -r rm -r --
```

Comment: What is the point of `find` there? `ls -td ./*/` does the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all but the most recent X files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

The following GNU solution is a little overkill but it's robust.

GNU `find` has a `-printf` predicate that allows to prepend the modification time to the outputted paths. You can then `sort` those `modtime`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`path` entries, drop the first four & strip the modification time with `sed`, and then `rm` the remaining ones.

```bash
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Ts\t%p\0' |
sort -zr -k1,1 |
sed -z '1,4d; s/^[^\t]*\t//' |
xargs -0 rm -r
```